# Why can't I prove that the regular language is closed under concatenation by this way?

Tags: regular-languages

I'm reading Michael Sipser's "Introduction to the Theory of Computation", and it says:

> THEOREM 1.26
> The class of regular languages is closed under the concatenation operation

In [the video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9syvZr-9xwk&list=PLUl4u3cNGP60_JNv2MmK3wkOt9syvfQWY&index=1&ab_channel=MITOpenCourseWare), if we scroll to the last section, he said that we cannot prove this by "concatenating" `m1` and `m2` together and pointing all accepted states of `m1` to the starting state of `m2`.

I don't get why this doesn't work (he did explain a bit but I didn't get the point). From what I understand, if we pass `w1w2` (concatenated strings) through a "concatenated" m1 and m2, it first goes through `m1`, ends at one of the original accepted state (but not accepted anymore after the concatenation), and at this point the `w1` part of `w1w2` has been read so essentially it is equivalent to move `w2` through `m2`, which will definitely end at an accepted state.

Where did I go wrong with the above thought? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

Actually, that works if you add $\varepsilon$-transitions between final states of $M_1$ and the initial state of $M_2$.

His argument of "maybe the cut of $w$ was wrong and you should have waited longer" is flawed if you consider nondeterministic automata, which are made to explore all possibilities at once.

What doesn't work, though, is if those transitions are labelled by an alphabet symbol, and not $\varepsilon$.

Answer (score 1):

I would assume you are familiar with regular expressions since that was discussed in the video you linked. However, it seems like nondeterminism hasn't been introduced.

Consider two regular expressions $a^*$ and $ab$. The first one represents the language that contains string made up of 0 or more "a", while the other represents the language that simply contains "ab". Lets assume we have machines $M_1$ and $M_2$ for the languages, respectively. If you simply attach the final states of $M_1$ to the start state of $M_2$, when will be the right time for the machine to jump from $M_1$ to $M_2$ if it is continually reading "a" from the input? Remember the machine cannot read ahead nor unread the input.